# Using Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm() to override fields in different record

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am currently utilizing Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm to pass field values to a different record in crm.

I want to be able to overwrite the existing field values in the destination record with the parameter values I send with the method.

My current code line looks like this:

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account", GUID, parameters);
```

The GUID is obtained through a lookup field in the current form, as well as the parameters.

The code currently navigates to the specified record based on the GUID and writes the parameters to only the empty fields. Non empty fields are not affected by this.

I understand that the current approach may not be the best option for working with existing records.
I want to be able to overwrite existing fields; am I going in the right direction?

Comment: If you are planning to open the form with the values pre-populated yes you are on the right path, if you just need to update the values, without showing anything to the user, i suggest you to use rest calls (check on codeplex for crmrestkit)

Comment: Assuming you are setting the fields inside the onload event (?), are those fields read-only by any chance? a little code would be great to help you further....

Comment: the 'openEntityForm()' function is the only line that executes to navigate to the other form. The fields that I am trying to override are not read only. The problem here is that the function only populates empty fields with the given parameters and ignores fields on the target form that are already populated. There is currently no on load script being executed on the destination record as I do not know how to retrieve those parameters from the call on the other side

Answer (score 0):

There are some points to be considered while we are trying to set values using OpenEntityForm like values passed cant be script, values passed must be valid as per the data type and so on. MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375(v=crm.6)) has some more details on this. Hope this guides you closer to solving the issue.